# CORBA Type support, always appends :1.0?

Tags: c++, corba

I'm working with a middleware that utilizes `CORBA` as the transport mechanism.

I've noticed that all the `TypeSupport` types are appended with `:1.0`. Why is this? What does this value mean?

Example:
`IDL:JARSSRT/OptionTypeSupport:1.0`

I've googilized the interweb for an answer, but to no avail. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are CORBA repository IDs, sometimes also called Type IDs. They are simply identifiers for the type in question.

[This page](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/more-details-on-idl.html#htoc93) describes them in great and helpful detail.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to avoid object splicing with distributed systems and was hoping the middleware could use the type identifiers to make the distinction. This was exactly the resource I was looking for.